# How to run a script that logs in to the internet at boot (before user login) on ubuntu

Tags: java, python, ubuntu

I have made a script in Java and Python that logs in to my internet. I want to run one of it on my Ubuntu 14.10 at boot (before user login). How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Look into Cron, Ubuntu's task scheduler.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

the `@reboot` command should get programs running on startup.

Answer (score 0):

If you put it in `~/.bashrc` it will run at the same time you log in